# javascript date getting NAN in Internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, nan, explorer

```
var date = new Date("14-Jan-16 12:06");
alert(date.getDate()); //Getting NaN
```

But its working in other browsers not in IE. Any suggestions please

Comment: try changing the format or make a default date with `new Date();` and test the result. Some browsers doesn't support every date format. Here is a list of formats that work: http://biostall.com/javascript-new-date-returning-nan-in-ie-or-invalid-date-in-safari/

Answer (score 0):

Try this format:
`var date = new Date("January 14, 2016 12:06:00");`

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

use new Date(Year,Month,Day,Hour,Minute,Second,Millisecond);

```
var date = new Date(2015,2,14,12,6,0,0);
alert(date.getDate());
```